# Issues on Communication between an Application using Dot Net and IIS based server

Tags: .net, windows, iis, tcp, connection-timeout

An issue has been passed to me to look into that is really stumping me.
At first, it was under the generic guise of "There must be a network issue please look into this" (always seems to be blamed first), But on further digging, we're left with fewer and fewer clues.
I'll try my best to explain the issue im stuck with.

The client is a custom .Net based application sending POST/GET requests to an IIS-based web server. Normally we see no issues, however in busy periods where lots of requests are being sent we get a Task Cancelled from the client due to no response from the server.

Looking at the network level, we only see TCP-FIN and TCP-RESET-FROM-SERVER between server and client. Nothing jumps out on Packetcaptures as an issue, be it captured on either end, or the firewalls in the middle.

TCP-FINs are expected behavior, TCP-RESET-FROM-SERVER is when the Web Server severs the connection due to default timeout (2mins).

The client application is meant to re-use connections during busy periods, rather than close after every request.

We initially thought that the Client could be maxing out sockets before retry causing this error, however (the app has a maximum of 40 concurrent, and the client is set to 1000, with 5 apps per client).

Using Netstat though we see that socket count is much lower than 40, quite often not exceeding 20 even when this error occurs. (that includes time_wait status), so not sure if this needs deeper diagnoses or can be "cleared" from suspected issues.

The Web-server has no log at all of the requests being sent to it, so the issue seems to lay between .Net sending and IIS receiving.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? or can advise on how to dig further?

Currently running Windows Server2016 on both client and Server, Firewalls are Palo Altos managing Routing. We're nowhere near hitting hardware Cap issues when this issue presents itself.

So we've gone through with packet captures at all points, and nothing jumps out there as being an issue. We cant track individual requests through packets as it's all encrypted (production instance).

The exact error the client gives is:
[Error] [appstuff.Httpclient] RequestID: XXXX communication with web service invocation, exception on invoke with request type Post and request uri apistuff
system.aggregate.exception: one or more errors occured ---> system.threading.tasks.task.canceled.exception. a task was cancelled
---end of inner exception stack trace----
at system.threading.tasks.task1.GetResultCore(boolean waitCompelteNotification)
at appstuff.httpclient.invoke(http request type, string requesturi, object request parameter, string authentication)  in appstuff.httpclient.cs:line 200
----->inner exception #0 system.threading.tasks.taskcenceledexception: a task was cancelled <----

From our reading, the job to invoke the web request was canceled due to receiving no response.

Current thinking on our end is that the Code might not actually be passing this to the network, hence the no response.

Kind Regards,

Comment: IIS is the web server, so strange to see you wrote "IIS-based web server". With that in mind, I also doubt if "The Web-server has no log at all of the requests being sent to it" is true, or you just missed the actual logs. Before jumping to a conclusion, there is a lot more to collect from that server, but you'd better find a really good IIS professional to assist.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for my bad phrasing. 
We've dived into the %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles folder that IIS is using and can only see successful requests to the server (as well as results as requests and some extra data). 

Also looked into win error logs provided within Event Viewer where we can see the connections being timed out. 

Currently installing the extra Server role for enhanced IIS logging

Comment: With that added to the picture, I think your next focus should be on the time taken field in IIS log files for those requests when the client reported exceptions. If the values were very large, then this web app was unable to handle the load and the developers should analyze the situation further (profiling with load, or hang dump analysis) and take actions.

Comment: That's the tricky thing, there is nothing in the IIS logs to reflect the timeouts from the client side. No errors at all. (unless the extra logging role adds some we've yet to see)
The only timeouts we see in IIS are when the client doesn't close the connection and default timeout hits.

Comment: It will be relatively hard to track down further if your team didn't capture network packets on multiple locations (browser, server, as well as somewhere in the middle). By reconstructing the connections, packets and how long each stops took, you can then determine whether the issue was caused by the wire or the server. I don't think online forum can help much on such tough cases, as you are not supposed to share such data publicly.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Updated initial post for for information